# How to pass compare object or function to class function

Tags: c++, class, object, struct, compare

I'm going to implement data structures, segment tree, heap(priority queue).
However, I want to write it only one time and I can pass compare object or compare function into it so I can set it as max-heap or min-heap (in the past, I have to write 2 classes).

The question is how to pass compare object or compare function to class function

This is what I want to do

```
struct heap{
SomeType comp;

  void init(SomeType f){
     comp = f;
  }
...
}
```

and when I want to compare I'll use

```
comp(A, B); // << want it to return as bool
```

How can I set a compare object like `greater<int>` or `less<pair<int, int> >` to my struct ?

and if I want to write my compare object or function, how can I do it.

Sorry for my bad english
Thank you.

Comment: `std::function<bool(heap const&, heap const&)> f`. You might want to consider defining `heap` as a template with a compare parameter however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `heap` as template, something like following :

```
template<typename SomeType, typename Compartor = std::less<SomeType> >
struct heap
{
   // ....
};
```

Then can do :

```
heap<int, std::greater<int> > h;
```

Otherwise you can have a `std::function<bool(heap const& lhs , heap const& rhs )> func ;`
inside your `heap` and accept `func`  as argument in a member function from outside world.

Comment: How to use the comparator? I've tried `Comparator(x, y)` and it returns `error: no matching function for call to 'std::greater<int>::greater(int&, int&)' `

Comment: @kill-z First `Compartor comp ;` then you can use `comp()` . You may choose to initialize `comp` in all constructor initializer list too

Comment: Thanks, it works well. How about set Comparator to be `std::max`? Just change `typename Compartor = std::less<SomeType>` to `typename Compartor = std::max<SomeType>` ? I've tried but it won't work.